# Не получается написать запрос HQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mvc, hql

Пишу программу на Spring MVC + thymeleaf

Даны две таблички:
1.Сотрудники(FK на id Отпуска) 
2.Отпуск(FK на id Сотрудника)
  -дата начала отпуска
  -дата конца отпуска

Не получается написать запрос на сортировку по дате и отправить его в html.

html:

```html
<form th:action="@{/employeeVac}"  method="get" >
    <input id="startVac" type="date" name="startVac" >
    <input id="endVac" type="date" name="endVac" >
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Сортировать</button>
</form>
```

controller:

```html
  @RequestMapping(value = "/employeeVac", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sortByVacationDate(@RequestParam(value = "startVac", required = false)
                                     @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate startVac,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "endVac", required = false)
                                     @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate endVac,
                                     ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("employees", employeeRepository.findByDate(startVac, endVac));
        return "index";
    }
```

и моя попытка обратиться к репозиторию с пользователями,понимаю,что не правильно пишу запрос.Закончились мысли уже на этот счет.

```html
  @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e,Vacation v WHERE v.employee.id=e.id and v.startVacation between :startVac AND :endVac" )
    List<Employee> findByDate (@Param("startVac")LocalDate startVac,@Param("endVac") LocalDate endVac);
```

Что думаете?

Comment: Использую Postgresql,Hibernate,Spring Boot,thymeleaf!

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден!
Была ошибка в запросе,бился несколько часов .

```html
@Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e,Vacation v WHERE v.employee.id=e.id and (v.startVacation between :startVac AND :endVac)" )
```